# How to understand these email header fields? ("From" field prefixed with a "greater" sign)

Tags: email, rfc2822

I have a raw email with headers that look like this:

```
From xxxx@xxxx  Fri Apr 25 22:46:08 2003
>From xxxx@mxxxx Wed Feb 19 20:06:07 2003
Envelope-to: yyyy@xxxx
...
Date: Wed, 19 Feb 2003 22:05:59 +0500
From: "Actual Author" <xxxx@xxxx>
```

I don't know how to interpret **the first two lines**, and the initial reading of [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) has left me without a clue. They don't look like normal headers and manage to confuse Python 2.7 email parser (fine if I remove the `>` sign at the start of the second line). I have the same email body in Apple mail's cache, and it seems fine, so the input is clearly correct.

1. What's that header format? (`From <email> <date>\r\n`)
2. Why is the second one prefixed with `>` (greater sign)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a mail in [mbox](http://qmail.org./man/man5/mbox.html) format, where the first "From" line marks the start of the message. The second line (**>From**) seems to be caused by the escaping strategy of mbox known as **From quoting** - has this message been double-encoded as mbox?

Comment: Funny thing, though, is that I get this raw message body over IMAP (it was imported into Gmail from another mail server long time ago), and it's claimed to be RFC822 format.